# org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction is javax.persistence.RollbackException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Below there are five domain classes (dynamic programing). I need to update  records checklist header with two lists in it, these lists in turn have also two lists, so total of five domains. I need to update all five records, during update I get the following exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`new1`.`checklist_property`, CONSTRAINT `FK14E0B84E32ADD034` FOREIGN KEY (`checklist_property_title`) REFERENCES `checklist_property_title` (`id`))

I delete child records to put new records.

```
package com.stie.cmms.domain;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name = "checklist_header")
public class ChecklistHeader {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "checklist_name")
    String checklistName;

    @Column(name = "remarks")
    String prerequisite;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "equipment")
    Equipment1 equipment;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "checklistHeader", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<ChecklistFaultDescription> faultDescription;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "checklistHeader", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<ChecklistPropertyTitle> propertyTitles;

    public List<ChecklistFaultDescription> getFaultDescription() {
        return faultDescription;
    }

    public void setFaultDescription(List<ChecklistFaultDescription> faultDescription) {
        this.faultDescription = faultDescription;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getChecklistName() {
        return checklistName;
    }

    public void setChecklistName(String checklistName) {
        this.checklistName = checklistName;
    }

    public String getPrerequisite() {
        return prerequisite;
    }

    public void setPrerequisite(String prerequisite) {
        this.prerequisite = prerequisite;
    }

    public Equipment1 getEquipment() {
        return equipment;
    }

    public void setEquipment(Equipment1 equipment) {
        this.equipment = equipment;
    }

    public List<ChecklistPropertyTitle> getPropertyTitles() {
        return propertyTitles;
    }

    public void setPropertyTitles(List<ChecklistPropertyTitle> propertyTitles) {
        this.propertyTitles = propertyTitles;
    }
}

//above is first domain class
package com.stie.cmms.domain;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name = "checklist_property_title")
public class ChecklistPropertyTitle {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "checklist_header")
    ChecklistHeader checklistHeader;

    @Column(name = "title")
    String title;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "checklistPropertyTitle", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<ChecklistProperty> properties;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ChecklistHeader getChecklistHeader() {
        return checklistHeader;
    }

    public void setChecklistHeader(ChecklistHeader checklistHeader) {
        this.checklistHeader = checklistHeader;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<ChecklistProperty> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(List<ChecklistProperty> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}

//my third domain class 
// there are five domain class   
package com.stie.cmms.domain;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name = "checklist_fault_description")
public class ChecklistFaultDescription {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "checklist_header")
    ChecklistHeader checklistHeader;

    @Column(name = "title1")
    String title1;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "checklistFaultTitle", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<ChecklistFaults> faults;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ChecklistHeader getChecklistHeader() {
        return checklistHeader;
    }

    public void setChecklistHeader(ChecklistHeader checklistHeader) {
        this.checklistHeader = checklistHeader;
    }

    public String getTitle1() {
        return title1;
    }

    public void setTitle1(String title1) {
        this.title1 = title1;
    }

    public List<ChecklistFaults> getFaults() {
        return faults;
    }

    public void setFaults(List<ChecklistFaults> faults) {
        this.faults = faults;
    }
}
```

Comment: add @OneToMany collection orphanRemoval=true  in ChecklistPropertyTitle.class

Comment: I tried but still showing same problem

Comment: try cascade = CascadeType.DELETE this eror caused by you delete child but not update parent

Comment: offfcourse this error occurs during deletion of child.

Comment: actuall y what i am trying  dellete the child rows first then modifying parent with new object list . it works fine for first list "falultDes"  not in 2nd list "propetty title "  i even tried cascadeType.merge  still show s same proble as

Comment: I think add also orphanRemoval=true in checklist_property table this ,because orphanRemoval means when remove child items delete also parent

Comment: yes i knew orphan removal but exception is thrown before the operation of deltion  " integrity voilation  "  when delete queery is called in 2nd list it throwns itegrity voilation  exception  which it shouldnt throw also it  also throws only in 2nd list  thx

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.stie.cmms.repositoryImplementation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Expression;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.stie.cmms.domain.ChecklistFaultDescription;
import com.stie.cmms.domain.ChecklistHeader;
import com.stie.cmms.domain.ChecklistProperty;
import com.stie.cmms.domain.ChecklistPropertyTitle;
import com.stie.cmms.domain.ChecklistSearchModel;
import com.stie.cmms.domain.TaskChecklist;
import com.stie.cmms.domain.Workspace;
import com.stie.cmms.repositoryInterfaces.CheckListDaoInterface;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class CheckListDaoImpl implements CheckListDaoInterface {
    private EntityManager entitymanager;

    public EntityManager getEntitymanager() {
        return entitymanager;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntitymanager(EntityManager entitymanager) {
        this.entitymanager = entitymanager;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ChecklistHeader> listAll() {
        TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader> d = (TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader>) entitymanager
                .createQuery("Select l from ChecklistHeader l");
        return d.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public ChecklistHeader save(ChecklistHeader b) {

        entitymanager.persist(b);

        return b;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(long id) throws Exception {
        // entitymanager.remove(entitymanager.find(ChecklistHeader.class, id));
        TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader> d = (TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader>) entitymanager
                .createQuery("DELETE FROM ChecklistHeader c WHERE c.id=:id");
        d.setParameter("id", id);
        d.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public ChecklistHeader find(long id) {
        return entitymanager.find(ChecklistHeader.class, id);

    }

    @Override
    public ChecklistHeader update(ChecklistHeader b) {
        return entitymanager.merge(b);

    }

    @Override
    public long count(Workspace w) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TypedQuery d = (TypedQuery) entitymanager
                .createQuery("Select count(l) from ChecklistHeader l where l.workspace=:w");
        d.setParameter("w", w);
        return (Long) d.getResultList().get(0);

    }

    @Override
    public List<ChecklistHeader> getCostPage(int from, int to, Workspace w) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader> d = (TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader>) entitymanager
                .createQuery("Select c from ChecklistHeader c where c.workspace=:w");
        d.setParameter("w", w);
        return d.setFirstResult(from).setMaxResults(to).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ChecklistHeader> listAllWorkspaceRelated(Workspace w) {
        TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader> d = (TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader>) entitymanager
                .createQuery("Select c from ChecklistHeader c where c.workspace=:w");
        d.setParameter("w", w);
        // System.out.println("cost centre list size with proj id "+w.getId()+" is "+d.getResultList().size());
        return d.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public ChecklistHeader getByName(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader> d = (TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader>) entitymanager
                .createQuery("Select c from ChecklistHeader c where c.checklistName=:name");
        d.setParameter("name", name);
        ArrayList<ChecklistHeader> checkList = (ArrayList<ChecklistHeader>) d
                .getResultList();
        // System.out.println("total records" + checkList.size());
        if (checkList.isEmpty())
            return null;
        else
            return checkList.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(TaskChecklist checklist) {
        entitymanager.merge(checklist);
    }

    @Override
    public List<ChecklistHeader> listAll(Long id) {
        TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader> d = (TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader>) entitymanager
                .createQuery("Select c from ChecklistHeader c where c.equipment.id=:id");
        d.setParameter("id", id);
        return d.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(ChecklistProperty cp) {
        entitymanager.remove(cp);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeChecklistProperties(ChecklistHeader u) {

        //removingVal(u);
        try {
            System.out.println("id is"+ u.getId());

            Query q = entitymanager
                    .createQuery(
                            "DELETE FROM ChecklistPropertyTitle c WHERE c.checklistHeader.id=:id");
            q.setParameter("id", u.getId());





            //q.executeUpdate();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Long count(ChecklistSearchModel cSearchModel) {
        TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader> query = createSearchCriteriaQuery(cSearchModel);
        return (long) query.getResultList().size();
    }

    private TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader> createSearchCriteriaQuery(
            ChecklistSearchModel cSearchModel) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entitymanager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ChecklistHeader> cq = cb
                .createQuery(ChecklistHeader.class);
        Root<ChecklistHeader> fromCheck = cq.from(ChecklistHeader.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        predicates.add(cb.equal(
                fromCheck.<Workspace> get("equipment").get("workspace"),
                cSearchModel.getWorkspace()));

        if (cSearchModel.getChecklistName() != null)
            if (!cSearchModel.getChecklistName().isEmpty()) {
                predicates.add(cb.like((Expression<String>) fromCheck
                        .<String> get("checklistName"),
                        "%" + cSearchModel.getChecklistName() + "%"));
            }

        if (cSearchModel.getBuilding() != null)
            predicates.add(cb.equal(fromCheck.get("equipment").get("building")
                    .get("id"), cSearchModel.getBuilding().getId()));

        if (cSearchModel.getLocation() != null)
            predicates.add(cb.equal(fromCheck.get("equipment").get("location")
                    .get("id"), cSearchModel.getLocation().getId()));
        if (cSearchModel.getSystem() != null
                && (!cSearchModel.getSystem().equals(""))) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(
                    fromCheck.get("equipment").get("equipmentType"),
                    cSearchModel.getSystem()));
        }
        if (cSearchModel.getSubSystem() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(fromCheck.get("equipment").get("subtype")
                    .get("id"), cSearchModel.getSubSystem().getId()));
        }
        if (cSearchModel.getEquipment() != null)
            predicates.add(cb.equal(fromCheck.get("equipment").get("id"),
                    cSearchModel.getEquipment().getId()));
        cq.select(fromCheck).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
        return entitymanager.createQuery(cq);
    }

    @Override
    public List<ChecklistHeader> getPage(ChecklistSearchModel cSearchModel,
            Integer from, Integer rows) {
        TypedQuery<ChecklistHeader> query = createSearchCriteriaQuery(cSearchModel);
        return query.setFirstResult(from).setMaxResults(rows).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAssigned(ChecklistHeader checklist) {
        TypedQuery<Long> d = (TypedQuery<Long>) entitymanager
                .createQuery("Select count(c) from TaskChecklist c where c.checklistProperty.checklistPropertyTitle.checklistHeader.id=:id");
        d.setParameter("id", checklist.getId());
        if (d.getSingleResult() < 1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ChecklistPropertyTitle> findPropertyTitles(
            ChecklistHeader chklistHeader) {
        TypedQuery<ChecklistPropertyTitle> d = (TypedQuery<ChecklistPropertyTitle>) entitymanager
                .createQuery("Select l from ChecklistPropertyTitle l where l.checklistHeader.id=:id");
        d.setParameter("id", chklistHeader.getId());
        return d.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ChecklistFaultDescription> findFaultDescription(
            ChecklistHeader chklistHeader) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            TypedQuery<ChecklistFaultDescription> d = (TypedQuery<ChecklistFaultDescription>) entitymanager
                    .createQuery("Select l from ChecklistFaultDescription l where l.checklistHeader.id=:id");
            d.setParameter("id", chklistHeader.getId());
            return d.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAssignedF(ChecklistHeader checklist) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TypedQuery<Long> d = (TypedQuery<Long>) entitymanager
                .createQuery("Select count(c) from TaskChecklist c where c.checklistfaults.checklistFaultTitle.checklistHeader.id=:id");
        d.setParameter("id", checklist.getId());
        if (d.getSingleResult() < 1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public void removingVal(ChecklistHeader u)
    {
        Query q = entitymanager
                .createQuery(
                        "DELETE FROM ChecklistFaultDescription c WHERE c.checklistHeader.id=:id");
        q.setParameter("id", u.getId());

        q.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Class clazz, Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Query q = entitymanager
                .createQuery(
                        "DELETE FROM " + clazz.getName()   +  " c WHERE c.checklistHeader.id=:id");
        q.setParameter("id", id);

        q.executeUpdate();
    }


}
```

Comment: do not perform execute update in first deletion operation